# why is counit called the trace map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, then
$f_*$ and $f^*$ form an adjoint pair inducing natural
correspondence
$\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(f^*\mathcal{G},\mathcal{F})=
\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(\mathcal{G},f_*\mathcal{F}) $

Is there there any historical background why the
counit map $f_*f^* \to \text{id}_{\mathcal{O}_X}$
deserves the name a "trace map" [see [these notes](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Ejlipman/DualityTalk.pdf) on page 12]?
In other words there some toy
example
from where this terminology historically arose?

I know that in algebraic geometry one calls in context of
Serre duality [e.g. in Hartshorne's AG, Chap. III.7] the "trace
map" $t: H^0(X, \omega_X) \to k$ for proper scheme $X$ over
field $k$ admitting doulizing sheaf $\omega_X$.
Is this "trace" related somehow to the adjunction above?

Moreover does this have some loose connection to what one
calls "trace" in linear algebra, eg if $f$ is considered to
be finite, flat between nonsingular integral schemes?

Comment: It looks like the counit of your adjunction maps $f^*f_*$ to the identity, instead of $f_*f^*$ (which does not even act on the right category).   I think what you need is a different adjunction giving a natural correspondence $Hom_Y(f_*F,G)=Hom_X(F,f^*G)$, in which case it might be more natural to write $f^!$ instead of $f^*$.   Or am I just badly confused?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that the linear algebra definition of the trace extends easily to the trace of an endomorphism of a free module, and from there to a locally free module.

If $f$ is finite flat then $f_* f^* \mathcal O_Y=f_* \mathcal O_X$ is locally a free module over $\mathcal O_Y$, on which $f_* f^* \mathcal O_Y=f_* \mathcal O_X$ acts by multiplication of functions on $X$, and $f_* f^* \mathcal O_Y$ sends a function to the trace of the endomorphism it induces on $f_* f^* \mathcal O_Y$.

I believe this is more-or-less the source of the name.

Comment: I suspect that an intermediate role was played by the trace map in a field extension $L/K$, which is the special case of this where $X = \text{Spec}(K)$ and $Y = \text{Spec}(L)$, but I think was defined much earlier.

Comment: make perfectly sense, that's seems to be the reason! one nitpick: in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4738950/if-a-resolution-fy-to-x-satisfies-rif-omega-y-0-and-rif-mathcalo-y/4739491#4739491) the OP considered as $f$ the resolution of (rational) singularities and called the situation when $f_*\omega_Y=\omega_X$ to be equivalent that "the trace is an isomorphism". How does it fit in the context of this question? What the OP meant  in the linked question by the "trace map"? Conjecture: does in this situation hold something like $\omega_Y\cong f^{*}\omega_X$, in order

Comment: to relate these two notions of "trace maps"?

Comment: @JackYo For $f \colon X \to Y$ there is a map $f_* \omega_X \to \omega_Y$ which I think makes sense in singular settings as a map between dualizing complexes. I believe this is called the trace map by analogy.

Comment: @JackYo see e.g. (3.22.1) of Rational singularities by Kovács https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.02269.pdf